# Change height of UITabBar in iOS8 iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

I have created my own custom UITabBar with custom frame size. All it works fine in iOS5,6,7 but in iOS8 UITabBar height is not changing from 49px to 85 px. in iPad only.

Please suggest a good solution ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried?

```
self.tabBar.frame.height = 40
```

Comment: Yes! height change works proper in iOS5,6 & 7 but in iOS8 height is not changing.

Comment: so how will i get an answer - Paolo Stefan